# Invariant factors of matrix - does the order matter here?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix $A$ which has characteristic and minimal polynomials

$$\chi_A(t)=m_A(t)=(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)(t-\gamma),$$

for $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ distinct.

The invariant factors have to divide $m_A(t)$ and divide each other successively, so would they be $(t-\alpha)$, $(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)$, $(t-\alpha)(t-\beta)(t-\gamma)$ up to some relabelling of $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$? Is there any kind of condition on what the correct order should be?

Comment: What is your definition of invariant factors? If you want $\bigoplus R[t]/p_i(t)$ with $p_i \mid p_{i+1}$ to be the decomposition then there will be only one term with $p_1(t) = m_A(t)$ in this case.

Comment: @ronno They are what you’d get as the diagonals of the Smith Normal Form

Comment: They will be $1, 1, m_A(t)$.